# Average elements of an array between 2 percentiles

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have 2 vectors of length 200, say A and B; then I find every second percentile of the array A using 
A1=prctile(A, [1:2:100],1); 
so that A1 is an array of length 50. Now I want to find the average of the elements of A that fall within each two elements of A1( ie. average of elements of A between 2nd and 4th percentile) and also average the corresponding elements of B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My idea to solve this with a good performance is creating a 'label' vector which assigns a label (number between 1 and 51) to each of the bins defined by the 50 percentiles.

```
%Get the indices where each new percentile bin starts
[sortedA,indexA]=sort(A);
sortedB=B(indexA);
percentile_indices=ceil(prctile(1:numel(A), [1:2:100]));
label=zeros(size(A));
label([1,percentile_indices])=1;
%Convert this to a vector which assigns an index to each bin
label=cumsum(label);
%accumulate. Take the mean of all values with the same label.
prctileMeanA=accumarray(label(:),sortedA,[],@mean);
prctileMeanB=accumarray(label(:),sortedB,[],@mean);
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel, That solves a part of my problem, I actually wanted to get values of B corresponding to A, like if the elements of A within 2nd and 4th percentile are [2,8,19] which may be the 16th, 22nd and 112th element in the array A of length 200,  then I also need sum of the 16th 22nd and 112th elements of the vector B.. @Daniel

Comment: @Sourangsu: Updated the answer.